Is the language $\{0^i1^ic0^{i+1}1^{i+1}\mid i\geq 0\}$ context free?
Is the language $L=\{0^i1^ic0^{i+1}1^{i+1}\mid i\geq 0\}$ on $\Sigma=\{0,1,c\}$ context free? If it is, what is the grammar?
I know that $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ is not context-free, and my intuition is that $L$ is probably more complex than it, but I'm having difficulty proving that. Could anyone give me some help? Thanks a lot.

A quick intuition for why the language doesn't look context-free is that a pushdown automaton trying to decide would forget the value of $i$ while checking that the first block of $1$s has the same length as the preceding block of $0$s. It then can't check that the second block of $0$s is exactly 1 digit longer.
To actually prove that it is not context-free, you can use the pumping lemma. Given pumping length $k \in \mathbb{N}$, pick $0^k1^kc0^{k+1}1^{k+1}$ as your word. If $0^k1^kc0^{k+1}1^{k+1} = vwxyz$ with $|wxy| \leq k$ and $wy \neq \varepsilon$ then $vw^2xy^2z$ doesn't belong to the language. To prove the latter, make a case distinction on $wy$ containing $c$, it not intersecting the first block of $0$s and it not intersecting the last block of $1$s.
